# How do you concatenate two fields alphabetically with DAX (PowerBI)?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to concatenate entries from two columns into a comma-separated list, but need the result to be alphabetical.

The data:

`PRIMARY_ORGAN | SECONDARY_ORGAN
--------------|----------------
Kidney        | Heart
Heart         | Kidney
Liver         | Kidney
Liver         | Heart`

The desired result:

`Heart, Kidney
Heart, Kidney
Kidney, Liver
Heart, Liver`

In other words, it doesn't help to simply sort the two columns first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CONCATENATEX` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/concatenatex-function-dax) allows arguments that indicate the order to concatenate a list.

```
Concat = CONCATENATEX(
             {Organs[PRIMARY_ORGAN], Organs[SECONDARY_ORGAN]},  --List to concatenate
             [Value],                                           --Values to concatenate
             ", ",                                              --Delimiter
             [Value],                                           --Order By
             ASC                                                --Order Direction
         )
```

The reason it's `[Value]` is that I manually declared a list using the `{,}` syntax without assigning any column name. If you want to assign a name for some reason, you can use the `SELECTCOLUMNS` function. E.g.

```
Concat = 
    VAR List = SELECTCOLUMNS(
                   {Organs[PRIMARY_ORGAN], Organs[SECONDARY_ORGAN]},
                   "Organ", [Value]
               )
    RETURN CONCATENATEX(List, [Organ], ", ", [Organ], ASC)
```